# Keyevents with self - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this bit of code here:

```
from tkinter import *

class player():
    def __init__(self, xcoor = 0, ycoor = 0):
        self.xcoor = xcoor

    def leftKey(self, event):
        self.xcoor += 1
        print("Right key pressed")

    def rightKey(self, event):
        self.ycoor += 1
        print("Left key pressed")

world = Tk()
p1 = player()

world.bind('<Left>', player.leftKey)
world.bind('<Right>', player.rightKey)

world.mainloop()
```

When I run this and try the keys, whether right or left, I get this error:

```
TypeError: leftKey() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
Exception in Tkinter callback
```

I think the error is because (self, event) is wrong, but how do I fix that? I want it such that if an object of this class is created, its xcoor and ycoor will change when calling this function via keybindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the player object’s methods instead:

```
world.bind('<Left>', p1.leftKey)
world.bind('<Right>', p1.rightKey)
```

Otherwise, `player.leftKey` and `player.rightKey` will refer to the unbound methods that still expect a `player` object as the first argument (`self`). By referencing the methods from the player object, that argument is implicitely set. This is the same behavior you get when you just do `p1.leftKey(evt)` which is really just the same as `player.leftKey(p1, evt)`.

Comment: This somewhat helped thanks! But I still get this error: http://prntscr.com/94xf6i

Comment: @Katie2423 You forgot to add `self.ycoor = ycoor` into the `__init__` method.